# Trouble Logging out User After Inactivity in React Native (Expo) and Amplify

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, aws-amplify

I'm having some trouble understanding the best way to log a user out after, say 5 minutes, or x amount of inactivity. I've seen a lot of hacky solutions, and npm packages, but I'd much rather do it correctly and efficiently without needing to add any additional packages.

Here are some of the related dependencies I'm using in `package.json`:

```
   "aws-amplify": "^1.1.6",
   "aws-amplify-react": "^2.0.5",
   "aws-amplify-react-native": "^2.0.1",
   "expo": "^30.0.0",
   "react-native": "^0.55.0",
   "react-navigation": "^2.13.0",
   "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
   "redux": "^4.0.0",
   "redux-promise": "^0.6.0"
```

Here's my `App.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Font, Asset, AppLoading } from 'expo'
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise'
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify'
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator'
import reducers from './src/reducers'
import awsExports from './src/aws-exports'

Amplify.configure(awsExports)
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      fontLoaded: false,
      isReady: false,
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'NunitoSans-Bold': require('./src/assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Bold.ttf'),
      'NunitoSans-Regular': require('./src/assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Regular.ttf'),
      'NunitoSans-SemiBold': require('./src/assets/fonts/NunitoSans-SemiBold.ttf'),
    })
    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })
  }

  cacheResourcesAsync = async () => {
    const images = [
      require('./assets/fav.png'),
      require('./assets/splash.png'),
    ]

    const cacheImages = images.map(image => ( Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync()))
    return Promise.all(cacheImages)
  }

  render() {
    const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)
    return (
      this.state.fontLoaded && this.state.isReady ? (
          <Provider store={ store }>
              <AppNavigator />
          </Provider>
      ) : (
          <AppLoading
            startAsync={ this.cacheResourcesAsync }
            onFinish={ () => this.setState({ isReady: true }) }
            onError={ console.warn }
          />
      )
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

In Account Settings, I have a successful Logout Function, which is what I'd like to use after the user should be logged out.

```
  handleSignOut = () => {
    cognitoSignOut()
      .then(() => {
        AsyncStorage.clear()
        this.navigate('Auth')
      })
      .catch(err => this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message }))
  }
```

I guess the biggest confusion for me is that Amplify has all kinds of documentation on how to keep the user logged in and how to refresh the token, but not much on forcing the token to expire.

I'd love any help I can get! Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Got my answer after `aws-amplify` responded to me. This is not a current feature but there is now a feature request for it ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1972)).

Here is the direct answer via aws-amplify:

> Amplify stores the jwt tokens for the user in the cache. We currently
>   only use signOut as a way to expire these tokens and remove them from
>   cache. You could have an inactivity counter and then call signOut as
>   soon as the limit is reached. There isn't any other way using Amplify
>   to expire these tokens as of now.

Hope that helps someone in the future!